# Converting geographical projection of extremely large file using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

**My Task**
I need to convert 9 x 14Gb GeoTiff files to WGS84 geo projection.  The rough size in pixels is about 200k x 100k.

The data-type is byte and it is not a subject to interpolation, it is some logical attribute.  For example, if `A = 20` and `B = 30` does not mean that overall region is 25 - it has completely different meaning.

**What I did**

- Started gdalwarp on Windows (takes lots of time, fails on some machines, never finishes on other)
- Started gdalwarp on Ubuntu (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz, 56Gb RAM, takes ~3 days for 50% and stops). Takes 100% of one core, low RAM and low HDD io, and also puts `Potential thrashing on Band1` message in debug-log.
- Modified arguments, e.g. CACHE_MAX, wa were set to some really big values.
- The command I use now: 
  `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1000 -wm 1000 --debug on $1 $2`

**Question**
What are my other options?

---

I have successfully downloaded and compiled GDAL Beta 2. I have also placed entire source tif file in tmpfs (RAM). My current cmd is

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 99000 -wm 2000 -multi -co TILED=yes -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -wo STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=TRUE -oo GTIFF_DIRECT_IO=YES -oo GTIFF_VIRTUAL_MEM_IO=YES ram/2014/2014/2014_30m_cdls2.tif /mnt/test2.tif > test2.log 2>&1 &`

It does ~40% pretty quick (5 mins). Other 5 minutes, that I waited, it did not provide any output. From that point, gdal stops using more than one core.

Comment: Have you tried the `-multi` option? Have you thought about subsetting your datasets and mosaicking them after conversion? Can you post the exact command you tried?

Comment: @Kersten I have added the exact command.

Comment: For such huge files you should use -co BIGTIFF=YES option (https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2407), then maybe try Kersten's hint or take a look at GDAL 2.0 (beta) option of streaming operations- more info on page: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

Comment: @Kersten The -multi option does little help -- it starts using 2 cores, but then the `thrashing` debug-log occurs, and only one of two gdalwarp process uses 100% one core -- as without that option.

Comment: @jzol I will try `BIGTIFF` option, but I think gdalwarp is smart enough, because i see `GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(GTiff,/mnt/test.tif,191904,87956,1,Byte,(nil))
GTiff: File being created as a BigTIFF.` in debug log.

Comment: In that case have a look at the [warping options](http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a0ed77f9917bb96c7a9aabd73d4d06e08). You can invoke them with `-wo` and set the number of CPUs to be used as well as enable serial writing if that helps with your failing processes.

Comment: @Kersten looks like some options do not work
`Warning 6: Driver GTiff does not support GTIFF_DIRECT_IO creation option
Warning 6: Driver GTiff does not support GTIFF_VIRTUAL_MEM_IO creation option`

Comment: Check with gdalwarp if your original GeoTIFF files are tiled. Block size at the bottom of report is telling that. Also make sure that you create the warped GeoTIFF as tiled.

Comment: @user30184 did you mean `gdalinfo` ? Here is its output https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67c2f29498507433c449. I do not see any TILED options.

Comment: @Kersten could you please tell me what is `subsetting and mosaicking`? What tools should be used for that?

Comment: @user30184 `Band 1 Block=304x96 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette` does this mean it's tiled?

Comment: Sorry, definitely I meant gdalinfo, and yes, block size means that image has reasonably small internal tiles. How about output, does your gdalwarp command contain -co TILED=YES?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, the final command looks like `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1000 -wm 1000 --debug on -multi -co TILED=YES -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -wo STREAMABLE_OUTPUT=TRUE`, but it still stops using more than one core and drastically slows down at ~20%.

Comment: What is your GDAL version? If it is lower than 2.0-dev you may suffer from the issue that is discussed in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3120 and http://www.mail-archive.com/gdal-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg04106.html. Your cachemax and wm settings are now 1000 megabytes which is very much. Your original settings with big numbers could have been in bytes and thus actually less, read https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_CACHEMAX

Comment: @user30184 I have compiled GDAL 2 beta 2. Updated question with that info. Seems, not all is ok here, too.

Comment: I can only report the result from my own test with a Windows laptop and GDAL 2.0-dev 64-bit from gisinternals.com. Image sizes: input (RGB) `Size is 61440, 99840` output `Creating output file that is 114831P x 64751L`. Command simply `gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 test.jp2 -co tiled=yes output.tif`. Output 21 GB uncompressed RGB GeoTIFF was ready in 30 minutes. RAM usage 700 MB, CPU 12 %. You have paletted image but I do not know if it can make such big difference. And your image is more than three times wider.

Comment: @user30184 Tried the same on windows. Like before, stuck at 40%, eating up 1 core, 3.2Gb RAM and periodical disk reads.
Will try other options on windows.

Comment: Cut the image in 4 (or 8 or ...) and then warp each piece. Use nearest neighbor resampling so that values do not change (20 stays 20, never becomes 25). At the other end create a .vrt, virtual raster table, to mosaic the images seamlessly. ....actually now that I think about, first try creating a vrt for your existing images in the desired final projection.

Comment: @mattwilkie thanks for the answer, but I am not quite into this business. What is .vrt? How do I do it? Could you give some links about that?

Comment: maybe you should force -co BIGTIFF=YES, just to make sure that you start with the correct format. Using a lossless compression should also help -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE

Comment: @PolyGeo all options I tried did not give result in acceptable time. There is a bold text "question" that asks -- what could I also try? Anyway, the gdal supplied with QGIS seems to do the task.

Comment: I thought I had checked this for answers before closing it but it looks like I made a mistake because it already had two answers.  I should have checked more thoroughly when responding to the system flag raised on it.  I'm glad you received the answer you were seeking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks very strange, but warping with QGIS (which runs its embedded gdalwarp) is much faster!

**I was able to process 14Gb file in 70 minutes,** on windows, without much resource consumption. It still was not looking like it used multiple cores, but did the work, which is great. Also, it seems the same applies to gdal_translate.

Probably, they build gdal correctly, or something. The version is GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10.

*Small note:* on my files gdal_translate utility does all the work, but then places an error message: "incorrect file format: ". I ignored this message, because the file was correct.

Comment: this might be 64bit vs 32bit. In any case I'm glad you found a solution and thanks for sharing it. If you haven't already I would verify the end product has the right pixel size and wasn't resampled too coarsely (e.g. rule out the possibility Qgis was faster because it took a shortcut).

Comment: @mattwilkie as a final solution, I did not start QGIS at all. I just started gdal* tools from its setup folder.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest tackling this using [Virtual Raster Table](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html) (.vrt) format. How the end result is to be used will determine how many steps are needed.

Simplest possible case is the end product will be used by a GDAL or GDAL-aware program, create one .vrt in the desired projection and then use that in your final program:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs wgs84 -of vrt D:\gisdata\bigtiff*.tif test.vrt
```

This will probably only be feasible if the final program is using a small portion (view window) of the image at a time as the reprojection calculations happen at run time. This can be ameliorated by calculating overviews with [gdaladdo](http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html):

```
gdaladdo -ro test.vrt 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

*(nb: on my computer at moment this isn't creating external files like it used to. Might need to add some steps.)*

Mapbox has an excellent and detailed article on a complex workflow using very large images with virtual rasters and multiple calculation steps: [Super Sharp 50cm Pléiades Satellite Imagery on MapBox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/super-sharp-pleiades-imagery-on-mapbox/)